# How to make a POST request passing JSON as body with Bee Client (Scala)?

Tags: json, scala

I'm using [Bee Client](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client) as the http-client for my project and I would like to know how can I make a POST request passing a JSON as the body of my request.

I'm using [KairosDB](http://www.kairosdb.org) as database and I need to query data from `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/datapoints/query`. KairosDB expects a POST request within the following body:

```
{
    "start_relative": {
        "value": "5",
        "unit": "years"
    },
    "metrics": [
        { "name": "DP_391366" },
        { "name": "DP_812682" }
    ]
}
```

**How can I achieve a call like that using Bee Client?** I've searched for the Bee Client and I didn't find how to pass a JSON string as a body of POST or GET requests, just other arguments (like map).

*Please, note that this's a self-answered question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After search almost the whole [Bee Client API](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/docs/bee-client/0.28.0/) and part of it's documentation, I've found [this small code example](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/content/bee-client/making-other-types-requests) from Bee Client documentation that answers the question (check "Making PUT requests section).

**1) Import the following modules:**

```
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http._
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.request.RequestBody
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.response.Response
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.header.MediaType._
import java.net.URL
```

**2) After that, it's simple as that:**

```
// Creating our body within a JSON string.
val jsonBody = RequestBody("""{ "x": 1, "y": true }""", APPLICATION_JSON)

// Making the POST request passing the JSON as body of the request.
val httpClient = new HttpClient
val response: Response = httpClient.post(new URL(query_url), Option(jsonBody))

// Print to check the status of the request.
println(response.status)
println(response.body.asString)
```

---

If you want a real case example to better understand how it works, I've made the following code with a little help from [PlayJSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson):

```
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http._
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.request.RequestBody
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.response.Response
import uk.co.bigbeeconsultants.http.header.MediaType._
import java.net.URL
import play.api.libs.json._

object SimpleApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        // Creating JSON
        val query_url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/datapoints/query"
        val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
            {
              "start_relative": {
                    "value": "5",
                    "unit": "years"
                },
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "name": "DP_391366"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DP_812682"
                    }
                ]
            }
        """)
        val jsonBody = RequestBody(Json.stringify(json), APPLICATION_JSON)

        // Making API call
        val httpClient = new HttpClient
        val response: Response = httpClient.post(new URL(query_url), Option(jsonBody))

        println(response.status)
        println(response.body.asString)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!